# Implicity usage of Java Custom class loaders?

Tags: classloader

I've written some customer class loader that load some classes from a certain directory (that is not in the classpath), say:

```
class FileSystemClassLoader extends Classloader{
  // implementation details
}
```

I have some directory say `/home/mhewedy/classes/` that is not in the classpath, this directory contains some classes that I use the previous classlaoder to load.

how to use this classloader from the my code to load classes "simplicity" without writing : such code:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(new FileSystemClassLoader());
// some code here ...
ClassLoader contextCL = Thread.currentThread().getcontextClassLoader();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to respond to OP edits:

When the JVM loads a class, it will use the classloader that loaded the "current" class ([per JVM spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ConstantPool.doc.html#72007)). So if you're in method `Foo.main()`, which was loaded with your custom classloader, and you want to create an instance of `Bar`, also loaded via that classloader, you don't have to do anything special.

However, if your current method is `Baz.main()`, and it was loaded via the system classpath (specified with `-cp` on the command line), then you have to explicitly load that class via the classloader. There's no way around this. The "context classloader" is meant for application code, to load resources; the JVM ignores it.

In almost all cases, you're better off constructing a classpath that includes your special classes.

Comment: ahh, you mean, if I have class A loaded by my custom classloader, so any class loaded inside A will be loaded by the customer classlaoder ( the parent classloader ), right ?